# Errors when trying to install the Ubuntu Software Center and Wine

Tags: software-installation, wine, software-center, dependencies

I tried installing many apps already via terminal and all I get is errors. When I type:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software-center
```

all I get is

```
alex@alex-NV55C:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-software-center
```

I have also tried installing wine and after I enter via terminal

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

I get

```
alex@alex-NV55C:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.19-0ubuntu6) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.4 is to be installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.19-0ubuntu6.4) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing the existing Software center and then install by using the following commands,

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center



sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Comment: When I type the first command it shows

Comment: sudo apt-get remove software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.19-0ubuntu6) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.4 is to be installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.19-0ubuntu6.4) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
 ubuntu-desktop : Depends: software-center but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: The error message  itself is giving you clue:run in the terminal 'sudo apt-get -f install' without quotes